# Is there a way to redirect a browser to a file on the local network?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if it's possible to redirect to a URL like:

```
\\central\public\blah\test.html
```

in PHP? We want to put a link on the website for employees to quickly access tools that have to be kept on the local network for security reasons. Basically the link would  only work if you were in the office.

I've tried using:

```
header("location: \\central\public\blah\test.html");
```

but it just formats the URL to http://

Comment: I think you need to define the drive too on Windows (C:, D:, etc) or on Linux (root, usr, opt, etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enough forward slashes and the file:// protocol:

```
file://///central/public/blah/test.html
```

(reference: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=908015)

Comment: Hi @phpbob did this solution work? It does not work for me in Mac OSX

Comment: This does not work on Windows either

Answer (score 2):

try:

`header("location: file://central/public/blah/test.html");`

Comment: If 'central' is an SMB server name (as opposed to a director name on the local filesystem) then you'll need an extra '//' at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what browser you are using, but if you are using KDE (Konqueror), you can use the `smb://` prefix, like redirection to `smb://central/public/blah/test.html`.